# Using AND and OR in 68k language

Tags: assembly, boolean-logic, 68000

I need something like this:

```
if((ch > 'g' && ch < 'm') || (A >= 0 && A <= 100)) {
    // Do some stuff
} else {
    // Do some other stuff
}
```

`ch` is an 8-bit char, while `A` is a 32 bit integer.

I suspect I will need this code:

```
CMPI.B    #$67, ch
BLT       SOMELABEL

CMPI.B    #$6D, ch
BGT       SOMELABEL
```

and

```
CMPI.W    #0, A
BLE       SOMELABEL

CMPI.W    #100, A
BGE       SOMELABEL
```

How do I combine these using the OR and AND operators?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating spaghetti code with all those conditional branches, consider using `Scc` command, where cc is a condition. This command sets destination byte to $FF if condition is true and to zero otherwise. So you can have code like this:

```
cmpi.b #'g',ch
shi.b  d0
cmpi.b #'m',ch
slo.b  d1
and.b  d1,d0 ;now d0 is nonzero if all conditions for 'ch' are true
... same for A with result in d1
or.b   d1,d0
beq    else_branch
... here is 'if' branch
```

Comment: What does `shi` do? What is the "high" condition?

Comment: @MortalMan `shi` is just *greater than for unsigned numbers*. We have `sgt` with *greater than for signed numbers*

Comment: Here is an introduction for `Scc` commands: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25035030/understanding-the-scc-instructions-of-68000-assembly. Regarding `lo`/`hs` conditions, I think that most 68000 assemblers will just accept them as synonyms to `cs`/`cc`, respectively.